An IK Rigging Problem for a noob
I'm in need of a little help with an IK Problem and figured that this would be the place to get it while trying to work it out on my own. See the deal is that I'm trying to work out a Rig on my character here:

And while I think I'm doing okay I do need a bit of help getting the foot to rotate properly with the control rig of the IK part of the rig.
I've been following a tutorial along all nice and neat and everything online trying to get the IK rigging done so I can use said character for a Game I'm hoping to be working on, but Nothing I do gets it to work quite right and straight, and when I want to get the pose I've got here to a more, "T-Like" pose, it goes all weird like this: 
Can someone explain to me what's going wrong or what I'm doing wrong here? I've kind of stalled out on building my character here and would like to get back rolling on building, but this is proving to be a challenge. Here's the Tutorial I've been following along with as a reference here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIwrswJEFBQ&t=304s
Please and thank you for the responses, I hope that this isn't too much of a problem to ask for help with. :)

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

I think it is working as intended : the bones point toward the pole bone. Why does it have an offset and not being align with the knee ?

I believe it is, but I'm not in front of my screen with it pulled up in front of me now. I'm trying to make the leg move to as if the character would stand to attention, and I need to know what I'm doing wrong. The base pose is an A Pose.

hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Hey there, Here's the link from Google Drive to the Blender File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y0eewm4uhN_rqNhwm3RO19P7TICYuvf3/view?usp=drive_link
I hope this helps understanding what's wrong with the rig.

In what way is it wrong, could you please elaborate? The armature seems to work ok, you could parent the pole target to the IK controller but it's a detail

So when I start moving the leg on the armature -like if I wanted to move it back on the end of the walk cycle- it doesn't move totally straight. And when I want to rotate the foot with the IK Leg controller, the foot doesn't move at all, it only moves with the bone itself. Did I do the parenting wrong, or is it something simple?

I can't see what you mean, for the foot, parent it to the controller instead of the calf

So If I do that, then the upper part of the leg doesn't move. What do I do then?
